# How to replace a button link using SendGrid Api in C#

Tags: c#, sendgrid

I have a Transactional Template in my SendGrid Account, and I learned how to use it [here](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/master/USE_CASES.md), basically, any html tag that I want to change I do this :

```
msg.SetTemplateId("0000000-00000-00000-0000-0000000");
msg.AddSubstitution("-name-", "Example User");
msg.AddSubstitution("-city-", "Denver");
```

The problem is, if I had to put a link inside of a Button how I would do this. ?

```
<a href="http://www.MyCustomLink.com/"><button style="color:#607D8B; background-
color: white;
border: none;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 15px 32px;"
type="button">Confirm Account</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simply set the href's value to a substitution key.

For example:

```
<a href="-accountConfirmationLink-">
    <button>Confirm Account</button>
</a>
```

can then be replaced with

```
msg.AddSubstitution("-accountConfirmationLink-", "https://stackoverflow.com");
```